# "An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure" - running Nunit from jenkins

Tags: entity-framework, jenkins, nunit

I am running datalayer test cases using Nunit from Jenkins. The testcases uses entityframework to connect with database. My connection string:

> When I am running this test cases from Jenkins I am getting below
>   error:
>
> ```
> 2) Test Error : TaskMaster.Tests.TaskManagerControllerTest.EndTask    System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException : An exception has been raised
> ```
>
> that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a
>   SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.   ---->
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException : The underlying provider
>   failed on Open.   ----> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException : An
>   exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
>   If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using
>   SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.   ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   : A connection was successfully established with the server, but then
>   an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
>   ----> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : No process is on the other end of the pipe    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   TaskMaster.Data.Repository.GetTasks() in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test001\TaskMaster.Data\Repository.cs:line 30 
>   at BusinessLayer.TaskManager.GetTasks() in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test001\BusinessLayer\TaskManager.cs:line 34
>   at TaskMaster.Tests.TaskManagerControllerTest.EndTask() in c:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test001\TaskMaster.Tests\TaskManagerController.Test.cs:line
>   62
>   --EntityException    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean
>   shouldMonitorTransactions)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)
>   --EntityException    at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>   --SqlException    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)
>   --Win32Excepti

If I run the same test cases from visual studio tests run fine without any error. I have checked the connection string are same. Any help appreciated.

Note: I tried to use Integrated security in connection string. But in jenkins tries to login in database as NT Authority/Network Service and that user is not present.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? any idea ?